# best way to handle different events in golang

Tags: loops, go, events, event-handling

I want to implement in golang a method to react to three different kind of events:

- changes in a text file (inotify)
- Timerevents (timer has ended)
- Linux signal received (SIGUSR1)

The sw should wait infinitely for events in idle, and if events from filechanges, timers or signals get received, the according handling-functions should be called.
After the eventhandling the waiting for events should continue.

I had a look at channels, where for each of the events
a separate goroutine get used, but found nothing so far that would fit my demands..

Does anybody have a suggestion or example how this could be done in golang the best way?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Filesystem Notifications

https://github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify

## Timer Events

https://gobyexample.com/timers

## Signal Handling

https://pkg.go.dev/os/signal

https://gobyexample.com/signals

^ the `syscall` library supports SIGUSR1

Comment: Thanks spencer a lot.
But my question was not how to do FS notifications or Timer events, it was more about a good method to react to those thee types of events... 
Anyway thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? The links above have examples of how to use channels to accomplish what I think you're trying to do, unless I'm misunderstanding what that is.

Comment: I am trying currently with this: https://gobyexample.com/select
Sorry, but just posting some links without anything descriptive is for me hard to understand what exactly you are suggesting...

Comment: Your question asks how to respond to three different kind of events. I shared links with examples of how to respond to each of those events. I suggest you click on them and read what's there. `select` is a great way to put them all together, as illustrated in the `fsnotify` link. You could also have a handler loop in each goroutine and a shared error channel which you could block on in the main function.